# Django log create new log file after file size reach 1050KB

Tags: django, python-3.x, logging

I decide to create a log file and this log file i wish to have a maximun size limit (1050kb). If the log(testlog.log) size is full, i wish to create a new log file which is (testlog_1.log). I try below code but the file doest not create when it come to 1050KB.

```
log_format = "%(asctime)s::%(levelname)s::%(name)s::"\
         "%(filename)s::%(lineno)d::%(message)s"
today = date.today()

# dd/mm/YY
d1 = today.strftime("%d%m%Y")
filenameDate=d1
filenameDate=str(filenameDate)
logpath="D:\\Pin\\"+filenameDate+".log"
logging.basicConfig(filename=logpath, level="DEBUG",  format=log_format)
log = logging.getLogger()
handler = RotatingFileHandler(logpath, maxBytes=1 * 1024 * 1024, backupCount=100, mode="a", delay=False)
if (log.hasHandlers()):
    log.handlers.clear()
log.addHandler(handler)
fmt = logging.Formatter(log_format)
handler.setFormatter(fmt)
```

I get below error:

```
 PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D:\\Pin\\16022020test2.log' -> 'D:\\Pin\\16022020test2.log.1'
```

please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32806222/214892 might answer your question

Comment: I'd suggest to utilize `logrotate` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I have a handler.doRollover()  , it work but it simply create the file, i run once only it direct create few file event though the size is not full